# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: subquery

I try to update a table A column from select data from table B. However I hit the error message as stated above "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows `=`, `!=`, `<`, `<=` , `>`, `>=` or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Please find my code as below:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET CVT_FACTOR = (SELECT a.CVT_FACTOR
FROM TABLE_A a JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.PROD_CODE = b.PROD_CODE)
```

Please help as have stuck in this for hours now.

Comment: What database system are you using? In any case, your subquery is being used to apply a single value to CVT_FACTOR, but is capable of multiple value returns, so that's not a good design.  You should use the actual UPDATE/JOIN method rather than a subquery assignment, but without knowing the db engine, we can't advise what that syntax is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just run the subquery `SELECT a.CVT_FACTOR FROM TABLE_A a JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.PROD_CODE = b.PROD_CODE` you will find that it returns more than one row. This is not allowed when using it to update a value as you are doing.

What you probably want to do is:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET CVT_FACTOR = (
    SELECT TABLE_B.CVT_FACTOR FROM TABLE_B
    WHERE TABLE_B.PROD_CODE = TABLE_A.PROD_CODE
)
```

Comment: actually i figure out the query. In the end what I use is
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET CVT_FACTOR = A.CVT_FACTOR
FROM TABLE_B B JOIN TABLE_A A ON A.PROD_CODE = B.PROD_CODE

thanks, it actually works.